# Is it semantically correct to use an image in the dd of a description/definition list?

Tags: html

Is something like this semantically correct?

```html
<dl>
  <dt>Chicken and Vegetable Soup</dt>
  <dd><img src="picture_of_vegetable_soup.jpg"/></dd>
  <dd>1/2 cup uncooked orzo or pastina</dd>
  <dd>3 cups fat-free, lower-sodium chicken broth</dd>
  <dd>1 cup can no-salt-added, fire-roasted diced tomatoes</dd>
</dl>
```

Answer (score 1):

After doing some digging on www.w3.org, I found out that it is indeed semantically correct to do so.  The [dd element](http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/dd.html#dd) of the Description List allows for [Flow Content](http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/terminology.html#flow-content) which consists of [Flow Elements](http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/common-models.html#common.elem.flow).  These Flow elements do include images.

Comment: Semantic but not accessible.